# How to see specific information from the Motherboard

Tags: hardware

I know that for example:

`lshw` - Shows all the info for all hardware.
`lsusb` - Shows all connected USB devices.
`lspci` - Shows all PCI connected devices including AGP, PCIex and any other related.
`cat /proc/meminfo` - Shows information about the memory.
`cat /proc/cpuinfo` - Show information about the CPU.
`hdparm -Ii /dev/sda` - Shows information about the HDD.

But what about the motherboard. `lshw` is too generic. Is there a specific command for the motherboard. To show what the motherboard is capable of, name, version, slots, etc.. Information specific to the motherboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `dmidecode`

```
dmidecode --type baseboard
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0200, DMI type 2, 9 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: 0D8635
    Version: A01
    Serial Number: ..CN6970265R0638.

Handle 0x0A00, DMI type 10, 10 bytes
On Board Device 1 Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Embedded ATI ES1000 Video

On Board Device 2 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Embedded Broadcom 5708 NIC 1

On Board Device 3 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Embedded Broadcom 5708 NIC 2
```

For additional options, use `dmidecode --type`

```
dmidecode --type

dmidecode: option `--type' requires an argument
Type number or keyword expected
Valid type keywords are:
    bios
    system
    baseboard
    chassis
    processor
    memory
    cache
    connector
    slot
```

=)

Comment: Did not know about the --type thingy there. Thanks bodhi

Comment: It is more or less an error message, but helpful.