# Check what kind of hardware slots are available linux

Tags: command-line, hardware

My laptop comes in different models, some of them have an m.2 sdd slot. The retailer I bought it from doesn't provide information in great detail and I'd like to know without opening up the laptop if I have m.2 available.

Is there a command I can run to check that? Like lspci for example?

Comment: Can you provide the exact model of your laptop? (From the sticker underneath or wherever it is?)

Comment: Maybe the output of `sudo lshw -businfo` can give a hint?

Comment: Post the lshw output to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 12):

I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108954/how-to-see-specific-information-from-the-motherboard) will do it:

```
sudo dmidecode --type connector
```

For me, it shows a lot of ports - masses of USBs, a Firewire, ESATA and SATA connectors etc. I expect it will show an m.2 port - although it might have a different name - for example, my Firewire shows up as `P1394`.

If you're interested, [here is the output for me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24601088/), and [here is the output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24601103/) for just `sudo dmidecode`.

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but in my case the output does not list anything at all.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thats's strange - here's my output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24601088/

Comment: I only get the first three lines talking about versions and SMBIOS, nothing useful. No idea why.

Comment: It worked for me on a 64 bit 14.04 desktop system.  Asus hardware.

Comment: That only returned a list of USB, network, and mini-jack connectors.. I think if would have been there it should have listed PCI interfaces at least as well?

Comment: @simernes try the second command - `sudo dmidecode`

Comment: I did that both with --type and without, that's what I meant in my comment.

Comment: @simernes  that's really strange, let me do a bit of searching.

Comment: Mine shows the slots but doesn't display whether or not they are being used.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak I’m not sure mine shoes which are being used, but this was 2 years ago so my memory is poor! I don’t have Ubuntu on hand to test... `lsusb` will show you USBs that are plugged in... I’m not sure there’s a way to see ports and what’s connected.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if I had m.2 slots and if they were available, I used the following command:

```
sudo dmidecode --type slot
```

This gave me all the slots I have in the system and their availability.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Tim's answer, it didn't work for me like various comments under it suggest for others as well. Here is what I got a better result with:

`sudo dmidecode --type baseboard`